# Testing large data volumes in a developer Sandbox

Tags: apex

I'm trying to learn about large data volumes, but my sandbox has a 5 mb limit, and it's yelling that I've exceeded my storage space.... I currently have about 2 -3 k records and want to put in 50k opps to see if my soql statements are specific enough

Are there ways to get storage limit increases? If not, what's the alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That sounds about right -- 5MB is about 2,500 records.  (Each record in SFDC counts as 2k against your storage limits, with emailMessages and Campaigns being the two exceptions.)

The best way to make sure your SOQL statements are specific enough is to learn about query selectivity, how indexing works in SFDC, and other optimization best-practices, and see whether your code complies.  (If you had 50k records in your database, and your SOQL statements were failing, you'd have to start there anyway!)

One of the best resources is the Large Data Volumes guide [PDF]:
https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp.pdf

Otherwise, if you're developing apps for the AppExchange, it's worth joining the Salesforce Partner Community.  Once you're registered, you **can** request a **Large Data Volume sandbox** when you're ready to begin testing at scale.  Details under the "what you need to know" tab here:

https://partners.salesforce.com/s/education/appinnovators/Enterprise_Scale_Testing#z

Answer (score 4):

> Are there ways to get storage limit increases?

No. You'd have to actually to get an active org that costs money.

> If not, what's the alternative?

Are you a registered ISV?

If so, you can get a Partner Developer Edition, which has 250 MB of storage.

Do you have a production org configured for DX?

If so, you can create an Enterprise scratch org, which has 200 MB of storage.

Do you have a Full Sandbox, Partial Sandbox, or Developer Pro Sandbox?

These three sandboxes have the same storage as production, 5 GB, and 1 GB, respectively.

---

If you don't have access to any of the above types of orgs, you're probably out of luck.

Comment: And you can test the specificity of your query using the query plan tool

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have a Personal Developer Edition org (as you have mentioned 5 MB limit). You cannot get additional storage in a personal Developer Edition Orgs. Note that a Developer Edition org is not supported by Salesforce, so you don't have any option to get storage increased there.

Even if you had a paid edition say Enterprise or Unlimited, the storage limits on the different sandboxes viz., Developer, Developer Pro, Partial Copy are strictly enforced. Only your Full copy sandbox maps to the Production storage limit. Unless you have a licensed edition, you are out of luck to get any upgraded storage in personal developer edition org.

Here are few reference links around type of sandboxes and storage limits:

- [Salesforce Editions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=overview_edition.htm&type=5)
- [Data storage amount limit exceeded](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000213997&type=1)
- [General Sandbox and Sandbox Storage Limits](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=deploy_sandboxes_limits.htm&type=5)
- [Sandbox Licenses and Storage by Type](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_sandbox_environments.htm&type=5)